# Azure AD v2 endpoint consent takes time to be done

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I have a small demo JavaScript Single Page Application that uses MSAL.JS to call a back-end API.

When the user logs in, MSAL.JS redirects the user to login as normal with the necessary scopes in the URL. The user gets prompted for the permissions, and hits Accept. They get redirected back to the app, MSAL.JS tries to get an access token silently with a hidden iframe, but that fails.

It fails saying consent has not been given. But if I wait like 15 seconds, it works.

I am able to work around the problem by retrying the silent token acquisition for a while, but that is a horrible hack.

It seems like the v2 endpoint has a problem with caching or data propagation.

Comment: What happens the 2nd time around that user logs in (after consent)? Are you able to immediately acquire an access token?

Comment: They get asked consent again..

Comment: Acquiring it directly in the result is an option, but silent acquisition should work. I can only get one token back via implicit grant anyway.

Comment: Kinda looks like a bug in the endpoint. I'd open an issue here - https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues. I've never seen that with adal.js and v1, that one works reliably.

Comment: Same here, never saw this with v1. The product team mentioned this kind of questions about existing features can be asked here, but I'll make the issue too :)